# How do I use match() method with a for loop over a nodelist

Tags: javascript, regex, nodelist

When I collect a nodelist of p elements and apply a simple regex pattern using a match() method in a for loop, I get no matches in my test HTML which contains a known match.

When I use the same regex pattern on the whole document or on a string containing the pattern I am looking for I get a match. Doh!

I have demonstrated it in jsfiddle here
https://jsfiddle.net/rusty1642/fdcmn81h/

I tried using `paraText[i].innerHTML.match()`, to no avail.  I tried simply matching a known string like (/email/gi), I tried combinations of 'g' and 'i' qualifiers. Still nothing.

```js
var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
var paraText = document.querySelectorAll('p');
var listing = [];
for(var i=0;i<paraText.length;i++) {

listing += i+' '+paraText[i].textContent + '<br>';

var firstMatch = paraText[i].textContent.match(/\d{4}\s\d{3}\s\d{4}/gi);

}

var telString = "help@yay.com tel.. 0330 122 6000  postal address here";
var secondMatch = telString.match(/\d{4}\s\d{3}\s\d{4}/gi);

demo.innerHTML = listing;
demo.innerHTML +='<br>1 match with nodelist';
demo.innerHTML +='<br> result =>  '+firstMatch;
demo.innerHTML +='<br>2 match with simple string';
demo.innerHTML +='<br>result =>  '+secondMatch;
```

```html
<div>some SAMPLE address details in a page</div>
<p>Tel: 0330 122 6000</p>
<p>Email: help@yay.com</p>
<p>Address: New House Bedford Road Guildford Surrey GU1 4SJ</p>
<hr>
<div>
<b>the nodelist</b>
</div>
<div id="demo">nothing yet</div>
```

//the results
    some SAMPLE address details in a page:

```
Tel: 0330 122 6000
Email: help@yay.com
Address: New House Bedford Road Guildford Surrey GU1 4SJ
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
the nodelist
  0 Tel: 0330 122 6000
  1 Email: help@yay.com
  2 Address: New House Bedford Road Guildford Surrey GU1 4SJ

1 match with nodelist
   result => null
2 match with simple string
   result => 0330 122 6000
```

I would expect the match() method to find the telephone number in the nodelist as it looped thro, but it has not.

Can anyone explain please?

Comment: *"I have demonstrated it in jsfiddle..."* Please do live examples **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)), rather than off-site. People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you, it's **really** easy to forget to put something in the question that you've only included off-site, and copying the snippet to an answer is really, really easy for people trying to help you.

Comment: You included everything, though, which is great! So I made the snippet for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're only looking at the result of the **last** match in the loop. Since the last `p` doens't have the text, naturally that's `null`.

Perhaps you want to stop the loop when you find a match, see comments:

```
var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
var paraText = document.querySelectorAll('p');
var listing = [];
var firstMatch = null; // <=== Moved declaration
for (var i = 0; !firstMatch && i < paraText.length; i++) {
// Added -------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  listing += i + ' ' + paraText[i].textContent + '<br>';

  firstMatch = paraText[i].textContent.match(/\d{4}\s\d{3}\s\d{4}/gi);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
var paraText = document.querySelectorAll('p');
var listing = [];
var firstMatch = null; // <=== Moved declaration
for (var i = 0; !firstMatch && i < paraText.length; i++) {
// Added -------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  listing += i + ' ' + paraText[i].textContent + '<br>';

  firstMatch = paraText[i].textContent.match(/\d{4}\s\d{3}\s\d{4}/gi);
}

var telString = "help@yay.com tel.. 0330 122 6000  postal address here";
var secondMatch = telString.match(/\d{4}\s\d{3}\s\d{4}/gi);

demo.innerHTML = listing;
demo.innerHTML += '<br>1 match with nodelist';
demo.innerHTML += '<br> result =>  ' + firstMatch;
demo.innerHTML += '<br>2 match with simple string';
demo.innerHTML += '<br>result =>  ' + secondMatch;
```

```html
<div>some SAMPLE address details in a page</div>
<p>Tel: 0330 122 6000</p>
<p>Email: help@yay.com</p>
<p>Address: New House Bedford Road Guildford Surrey GU1 4SJ</p>
<hr>
<div>
<b>the nodelist</b>
</div>
<div id="demo">nothing yet</div>
```

Or if you want an array of the results attempting to match each paragraph:

```
var matches = []; // <=====
for (var i = 0; i < paraText.length; i++) {

  listing += i + ' ' + paraText[i].textContent + '<br>';

  matches.push(paraText[i].textContent.match(/\d{4}\s\d{3}\s\d{4}/gi));
// ^^^^
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
var paraText = document.querySelectorAll('p');
var listing = [];
var matches = []; // <=====
for (var i = 0; i < paraText.length; i++) {

  listing += i + ' ' + paraText[i].textContent + '<br>';

  matches.push(paraText[i].textContent.match(/\d{4}\s\d{3}\s\d{4}/gi));
// ^^^^
}

var telString = "help@yay.com tel.. 0330 122 6000  postal address here";
var secondMatch = telString.match(/\d{4}\s\d{3}\s\d{4}/gi);

demo.innerHTML = listing;
demo.innerHTML += '<br>matches with nodelist:';
demo.innerHTML += matches.map(function(match) { return "<br>result => " + match; });
demo.innerHTML += '<br>match with simple string';
demo.innerHTML += '<br>result =>  ' + secondMatch;
```

```html
<div>some SAMPLE address details in a page</div>
<p>Tel: 0330 122 6000</p>
<p>Email: help@yay.com</p>
<p>Address: New House Bedford Road Guildford Surrey GU1 4SJ</p>
<hr>
<div>
<b>the nodelist</b>
</div>
<div id="demo">nothing yet</div>
```

Comment: thank you, sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees.